# MediaElement.js jquery bug

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have an gwt application and I use MediaElement.js to show multimedia contents. If I put on the main page this script

```
<script> // using jQuery   
    $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();
</script>
```

to convert  and  tags in MediaElement.js and it doesn't work.

1. First because this script convert only one tag  or  in MediaElement.js
2. Second this tag must be before the script. If it is after it doesn't work.

So my problem is that I have more than one tag and this tags are created runtime so they will be after the script. I think that the correct work of the script should be:
 Convert all  and  tags within the page and not the only one before the script.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you can't move the script until after the tags, then you should either do

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('video').mediaelementplayer();
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
// your code
gwtCode();
$('video').mediaelementplayer();    
</script>
```